# Trouble understanding :state in Clojure

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop, gen-class

I understand what :state /does/. It creates a field, like in Java, in your class. What I don't understand is what is the point of this? It seems like I only see it done with Clojure-generated classes that extend other classes. http://www.fatvat.co.uk/2009/05/clojure-and-robocode.html being one example. I don't know Java, and I'm not very well versed in Object Oriented Programming. Can someone explain the point of :state to me, and where it all fits in with Java interop?

Thanks a lot!

NOTE: When I say :state, I am referring to (:gen-class :state)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I talked it over with hiredman on the #Clojure IRC channel, and he told me that the main point of it is a state per instance. That makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

:state is simply a way of sharing some data between the functions generated as part of gen-class.  Think of it as being exactly the same as the instance data of an object.

Answer (score 3):

More infomation on the `state` and how to initialize it can be found the article [gen-class – how it works and how to use it](http://kotka.de/blog/2010/02/gen-class_how_it_works_and_how_to_use_it.html)

From the article:

- `:state` defines a method which will return the object's state.
- `:init` defines the name of the initialiser. This is a function which has to return a vector. The first element is again a vector of arguments to the super class constructor. In our case this is just the empty vector. The second element is the object's state.

In summary, `init` returns the state of the object and is called when the object is instantiated.  `state` is a method on the class, as opposed to a function, that will return the same value returned as the second element in the vector returned by `init`.

The article then goes on to show how to use an atom to be able to change the state of the object, if needed.